# Vim map leader not working anymore

Tags: vim

I started recently making friends with vim. So far it is really fun  but actually I have the problem that all of a sudden my mapleader is not working anymore. When I display it with let mapleader it shows something like this:

```
mapleader              -
```

It looks like it has tabs or 10 or more spaces inside (not displyed here correctly). Did some of you had this before and has an idea what could trigger this?

Comment: Probably something in your vimrc file. [Try following these steps](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Comment: No, that's just the default formatting of `:let var`. Try `:echo strtrans(mapleader)` instead. And find the place where (probably in your .vimrc` this got defined.

Comment: Hi, I made it work again. I disabled all plugins made a cleanup in my vimrc and now it works like a charm. And yes, you are right it has nothing to do with the formatting :).